# How to get the SQS message attributes within the elasticbeanstalk worker tomcat?

Tags: tomcat, amazon-web-services

I have an elastic beanstalk application with Worker tier and tomcat 7.0, it works well. But I could not figure out how to get the message attributes from the POST call performed by aws-sqsd 1.1, I have checked all the headers, attributes, parameters and the body, but nothing.

After dig a while, I found that the aws-sqsd 1.1 was released on 2014-02-19 but the new feature of SQS message attribute support was published on 2014-05-06. So it seems reasonable that the aws-sqsd 1.1 does not support message attribute feature, is that right? Do we have any solutions to support message attribute in EB worker?

Comment: Did you solve it? How can you access to the message attributes from the Elastic Beanstalk worker for a non periodic task?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that this have been added in aws-sqsd 1.2!

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/using-features-managing-env-tiers.html

Comment: This is only for Periodic Tasks.

Comment: MatayoshiMariano, the AWS docs suggest the message attributes are present in all HTTP POST requests sent from the SQS daemon to your EBS worker, according to my reading. Do you have additional information from elsewhere, or from your experience?

Comment: Just to follow up, I have verified that these attributes are available to the EB worker via AWS's SQS daemon, not only for Periodic Tasks.

Comment: Some informal testing has shown that seemingly only message attributes with a name that can be translated unambiguously to an HTTP header name are passed as HTTP headers in the request. Message attributes named with underscores, periods, etc. are not included in the request. Hyphens are allowed. For example, "some_attr_name" gets dropped, but "some-attr-name" gets included.