# AWS SQS - Receive message from CRON

Tags: amazon-web-services, cron, message-queue, amazon-sqs

I have an AWS Elastic Beanstalk instance configured as a [Worker Environment](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/using-features-managing-env-tiers.html). It has a cron job that runs every x minutes. In Worker Configuration I have the path to a php file that runs when the cron fires. If I go to the SQS dashboard I can manually send the SQS for this worker a message as well as set an actual message, for example "hello".

My question is, how can I have the php file access the SQS message's message attribute?

The obvious answer is to use the AWS\SQSClient however the only way to read a message is to first get a message. The problem here is that the message has already been retrieved by the Elastic Beanstalk worker code. So how can I now read its attributes?

**EDIT**

Just to add more clarity to what I am describing I'm going to give a detailed write up of my steps to cause this.

1. I log into my elastic bean stalk and create a new Environment in my application.
2. I select 'create new worker'
3. I configure a PHP instance
4. I upload a new source for my environment

   1. The source zip contains 2 files cron.yaml and someJob.php
   2. See file codes below
5. I continue through set up until I get to the "Worker Details" section. Here I set the following:

   1. Worker Queue - Autogenerated queue
   2. HTTP Path - /someJob.php
   3. MIME Type - default
   4. HTTP Connections - 10
   5. Visibility Timeout - 300
6. I let the environment build
7. During the build an autogenerated SQS message and dead letter queue are automatically built
8. Once finished the environment sits there until the first cron job time is hit
9. A message is somehow sent to the autogenerated SQS message queue
10. someJob.php runs
11. The message apparently gets deleted

Cron:

```
version: 1
cron:
 - name: "Worker"
   url: "someJob.php"
   schedule: "0 * * * *"
```

PHP:

```
psuedo
<?send me an email, update the db, whatever?>
//NOTE: I don't even connect to the AWS file or perform ANY SQS actions for this to work
```

Now my question is, if I go to the autogenerated SQS queue I can select it, go to Queue Actions, go to send a message, and then send an actual message string ... such as "Hello".

Can I access the message message value "Hello" even though my PHP wasn't responsible for calling the message from SQS? Obviously, I would need to the call the AWS lib and associated SQS commands but the only command I can do is "receiveMessage" which I assume would pull a new message instead of the information from the currently received "Hello" message.

Note that sending the "Hello" message will also call someJob.php to run.

Comment: EBS stands for Elastic Block Store. I assume you mean Elastic Beanstalk. Also assume you mean SQSClient instead of S3Client. Your code that is reading the message from the queue should be able to get all the message attributes. If the message is no longer in the queue then something read it. So what did you code do with the message after it read it from the queue? And why do you also need a cron job to get access to that same message?

Comment: Mark, thank you for the edits .. fixed. What I'm saying is that my code doesn't have a "receiveMessage". By setting up a cron job for a worker, that by default, sets up an SQS queue for the worker. Apparently, the cron job sends a message to the SQS queue which the worker is monitoring for and when received runs the job. I'm wondering if I can see that message or if it is "hidden" on Amazon's side.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get the SQS message attributes within the elasticbeanstalk worker tomcat?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25639706/how-to-get-the-sqs-message-attributes-within-the-elasticbeanstalk-worker-tomcat)

Comment: @JohnRotenstein Hey John, thank you for updating this. So before posting this question I actually read the aws-sqsd 1.2 documentation linked in that comment. However, trying to pull against localhost did not yield any results. Wondering if you know of any better explicit instructions as the AWS docs can sometimes assume you already know the first 10 steps of making something work.

Comment: Ah, hold on. I didn't see the part about the POST. I'll try parsing the URL string as it sounds like that's where the data will be.